# Error Logging for MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, log4net, web-deployment, asp.net-mvc-5

This is the first time I am working with log4net and error logging. I am trying to deploy an MVC5 application. I have a location on network and the path is like `\\dev\wwwroot\scheduler`.

**What I have done so far?**

1) I published the project on the location with following configurations:

- Changed **Copy to output directory** to **Copy always**
- Changed **Build Action** for files in **Models** and **Controllers** folder to **Compile**
- Changed **Copy Local** for System.Web.Mvc , System.Web.Routing and System.Web.Abstractions to **true**
- After publishing the **Models** and **Controllers** folder gets copied inside the **\dev\wwwroot\bccscheduler\bin** folder on the location. [image]

[image]

2) And I start my application by giving **url** like *bccscheduler.dev.rgc.lcal/appointments/Details/?clientid=1001* When I run the application. I get **An error occurred while processing your request**

- But when I run the application on localhost then it works.The localhost url is *http://localhost:50137/appointments/Details/?clientid=1001*
- I the **url** *appointments* is the controller and **Details** is action method.
- The folder structure in Visual Studio looks like 
  [image]

3) I tried logging the errors by using **log4net**

- Created the **Logs** folder inside the project.
- Configured  **log4net** from http://weblogs.asp.net/jhallal/configure-log4net-logging-framework-for-mvc
- This creates a log file when I run my code locally.

**What do I need help with?**

1) How do I enable logging when I deploy the application

2) Is the folder structure correct on the network location as I always get the error when I give the url *bccscheduler.dev.rgc.lcal/appointments/Details/?clientid=1001*. What should I do to deploy the application correctly>

Comment: May be a security issue when deployed.

Comment: So the folder structure on network location is correct?

Comment: The network path is always going to be domain specific, so I can't answer that.  The MVC routing path needs to conform to your RoutingConfig.cs.  Post the error message, if you can.

Comment: Can you show your log4net config

Comment: This is the error message `An error occurred while processing your request`. And it is there in `Error.cshtml`

Comment: What is the `file value=` in web.config under `<log4net>` Is that using absolute path? or relative path?

In case if you have like `c:/` (absolute path) - it will auto create the folder. In case if you want to use relative path which is part of the application - you should create a new folder under your MVC application and name it as "Logs" and value must be `<file value="Logs/log4net.log" />`

Comment: @stuartd I have configured `log4net` exactly as given here http://weblogs.asp.net/jhallal/configure-log4net-logging-framework-for-mvc

Comment: @Thennarasan the path is relative. I have used `<file value="Logs/log4net.log" />` as given here http://weblogs.asp.net/jhallal/configure-log4net-logging-framework-for-mvc

Comment: Have you given the account running the app permission to write to that folder?

Comment: Maybe you just need: `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` in webconfig ...

Comment: Can you post the error that you get when you load `bccscheduler.dev.rgc.lcal/appointments/Details/?clientid=1001`

Comment: @stuartd I am always getting error while launching the application using network url. So I though error logging would help me figure out what exactly is causing that error. But the error logs dont get generated at network location.

Comment: @RudraniAngira If the directory and the file is not being created, then most likely, the configuration is not being read (and therefore used) at runtime.add the single line of code for Log4net that hooks up the configuration. This code usually appears in the bootstrap class in the application (e.g. Global.asax for an ASP.NET app).
`XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(configFile));` Instead of the above in-line, you can add this attribute to the AssemblyInfo.cs file `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]` - This will wire up the log..!

Comment: @Hackerman Could you please tell where should I add that. I dont see any tag with that name.

Comment: Inside `<system.webServer>` add this line: `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot run the application locally on your deployed server, try modifying your web config to include this:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb684665.aspx

This should provide you with a stack trace so you can figure out what exactly is going on.

Also, please post your log4net.config if it is a file/path related issue

Answer (score 1):

So many things can go wrong easily. First step to debug is to delete everything side `wwwroot`, and upload `index.html` which has just a simple html text like -

```
<html><body><h1>Test</h1></body></html>
```

If the web server can serve that index.html, then you create an empty ASP.Net MVC project *(similar .Net Target Framework as your original project)*, and  just HomeController and Index.cshtml. Then publish it to wwwroot folder.

If you can view the page, then it is a problem with your original application. If not, you need to check .Net Framework Version for the application in IIS.